# Display/create a blank row in between data set and breack the table data using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using one table and two queries to display the below output.

[image]

Here I have used 1st query to display the morning/middle/evening and other to get the user details.

I want to user a empty/blanks row after the last morning/middle which need to have this output

Expected output:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your SQL statemanets, i would only advise to use

```
UNION ALL
```

(See Docu [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html))

So your Statement would look somehow like that:

```
Select Col1, Col2
from tbl1
UNION ALL
Select NULL as Col1, NULL as Col2
UNION ALL
Select Col1, Col2
from tbl2
```